# Changing the behavior of YouTube API generated links

Tags: api, search, youtube, hyperlink

My goal is to display YouTube search results in my website based on a keywords search (e.g through YouTube API or GoogleCustomSearch using youtube.com), but change it so when you click on the link - instead of redirecting you to the youtube video page, it will get the link's URL and transfer it to a PHP file as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the result page with a CURL command, and use regular expressions to change the link urls to a link to your own link, wrapping the target url.

Something like this :

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJ87Lsx40PI
```

turn it into :

```
http://yoursite.com/youtube.php?XJ87Lsx40PI
```

Comment: Ina Lola, is there any chance you can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504297/changing-links-destination-generated-by-google-custom-search)? I'm struggling to understand how I can achieve my goal. Thank you